# MongoDB complex find

Tags: ruby, performance, mongodb

I need to grab the top 3 results for each of the 8 users. Currently I am looping through for each user and making 8 calls the the db. Is there a way to structure the query to pull the same 8X3 dataset in a single db pull?

```
selected_users =  users.sample(8)
cur = 0
while cur <= selected_users .count-1
  cursor = status_store.find({'user' => selected_users[cur]},{:fields =>params}).sort('score', -1).limit(3)
  *do something*
  cur+=1
end
```

The collection I am pulling from looks like the below. Each user can have an unbound number of tweets so I have not embedded them within within a user document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("51e92cc8e1ce7219e40003eb"),
    "id_str" : "57915476419948544",
    "score" : 904,
    "text" : "Yesterday we had a bald eagle on the show. Oddly enough, he was in the country illegally.",
    "timestamp" : "19/07/2013 08:10",
    "user" : {
            "id_str" : "115485051",
            "name" : "Conan O'Brien",
            "screen_name" : "ConanOBrien",
            "description" : "The voice of the people. Sorry, people.",
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's really difficult to tell as you've not provided much in the way of schema, etc. Often, you can use `$in` to grab multiple documents.

Comment: you definitely should read about [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) it resolves your problem

Comment: There's even a double [$group, with limit 3, ruby example](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/wiki/Aggregation-Framework-Examples) on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation).

Another way would be to keep track of the top 3 scores for in the user documents. If this is faster or not depends on how often you write to scores vs read to top scores by users.